# IdentationError: unident does not match any outer identation level. (Python)

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to coding Python and I'm learning it.

Now I've made a piece of code but keep getting the following error:

'IdentationError: unident does not match any outer identation level.'

I hope you guys can help me out.

```
password = test123


if password == raw_input('What is the password?'):
    print("Acces given")
  else:
    print("Acces forbidden")
```

Comment: ...just *look at it!*

Comment: just remove spaces before `else`

Comment: To add to @jonrsharpe's comment, look into the proper indentation for if-else statements.

Comment: Your `else` is indented and should not.

Comment: As a side note, your next error will be that test123 is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
password = test123


if password == raw_input('What is the password?'):
    print("Acces given")
else:
    print("Acces forbidden")
```

else need to be exactly below if statement. So, you need to unindent else, like i did. Python is about indentation, every thing in one indentation is   ranked same. So, in your case the else statement resides inside if. and the rule is you can't have else without if. So, it is giving error.

Comment: Explanation could be a plus since comparing removed spaces ain't easy with bare eyes...

Comment: This will still error because `test123` is not defined.

Comment: it could be defined somewhere up in the program

Comment: What are the chances ;)

Comment: if it was not defined , then the first line could have given error. If you try to  run the code. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
password = 'test123'

if password == raw_input('What is the password? '):
    print('Access given')
else:
    print('Access forbidden')
```

Further reading: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)